# Angular 2 tabset - Tabs talking to eachother

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Currently in my project I have an angular2 tabset that displays other html templates like so -

Tabs.html

```
<tabset class="Myclass">
  <tab heading ="Page1" (select)="sendMessageToPage2(Message)"<PageOne id="0"></PageOne></tab>
  <tab heading ="Page2" (select)="sendMessageToPage1(Message)"<PageTwo></PageTwo></tab>
</tabset>
```

Tabs.ts

```
import {PageOneComponent} from 'filespace.PageOne';
import {PageTwoComponent} from 'filespace.PageTwo';
import { TAB_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
  directives: [PageOneComponent, PageTwoComponent, TAB_DIRECTIVES] })

export class tabs {

public sendMessageToPage1(message: string){ do Stuff }
public sendMessageToPage2(message: string){ do Stuff }
}
```

My question is how do I actually get my message from page 1 to page 2, or get them to share a variable. Basically I need page 1 to ether react to a change that occurs on page 2, or run some function when tabbing back to page one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either emit an event from **PageOne** to the **tabs** component and then control the other component from tabs:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'PageOne',
  templateUrl: `<div (click)="onClick()">Click Me</div>`
})

export class PageOne {
    // creating EventEmitter to emit when onClick is called
    @Output() changed = new EventEmitter();
    onClick() {
        this.changed.emit();
    }
}
```

OR the better way is to share a service between those two components (PageOne and PageTwo) and communicate via the service, in short **tabs module** provides a service in the **tabs.module.ts|js** and **PageOne** and **PageTwo** as the components of the tabs module have access to it (DI in angular2) and then they communicate via that service, they can *publich/subscribe* messages, for more information please refer to

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html

and for *publih/subscribe* you can refer to:
https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm. Both are using the same service and using that to populate their views now.